# Change localhost to online server for app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, android-studio

I have created an small demo app as I saw on the following tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Xq2FUJvE-c

By using this video I have used Node.JS and MongoDB to create some database on my localhost and use it for log-in and registration.

Now, when I run the app on my emulator everything works perfectly and I see only how my database updates when I add new accounts and so on.

The next step I have tried was to download the apk and run it on a real device that is connected to the same WiFi connection as my computer where the database sits on.

I was wondering what actions do I need to do in order to use this database that I have created from my phone once I downloaded the app into it?

I saw that I might need to change inside the code from ip address of 10.0.2.2 to some 198.168 but it didnt work.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's no firewall blocking the access to your computer, just set the IP used by the app to the computer's IP.